# Get radio button value after change page on Jquery Mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I have 3 page of mobile web with Jquery Mobile.

index.html file

```
<div data-role="page" data-theme="a" id="index">
<div data-role="header" data-position="inline">
    <h1><img src="assets/images/logo_suggest_35_inv.png" alt=""></h1>
</div>
<div data-role="content" data-theme="a">
    <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true">
        <li><a href="flight/" data-transition="slide">Book Flight</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Hotel</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Train</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div data-role="footer" data-theme="a">
</div>
```

and this is the second file.

```
<div data-role="page" data-theme="a" id="search">
<div data-role="header" data-position="inline">
    <h1><img src="assets/images/logo_suggest_35_inv.png" alt=""></h1>
</div>
<div data-role="content" data-theme="a">
    <form id="searchform">
        <div class="ui-grid-a">
            <div class="ui-block-a">
                <input type="radio" name="trip" id="roundtrip" value="roundtrip" data-theme="a" checked="true" onclick="addDate()">
                <label for="roundtrip">Round Trip</label>
            </div>
            <div class="ui-block-b" id="onedate">
                <input type="radio" name="trip" id="onetrip" value="onetrip" data-theme="a" onclick="removeDate()">
                <label for="onetrip">One Way</label>
            </div>
        </div>  
    </form>
</div>
<div data-role="footer" data-theme="a">
</div>
```

this is third file.

```
<div data-role="page" data-theme="a" id="select">
<div data-role="header" data-position="inline">
    <h1><img src="assets/images/logo_suggest_35_inv.png" alt=""></h1>
</div>
<div data-role="content" data-theme="a">
    <!-- Show radio button if checked value -->
</div>
<div data-role="footer" data-theme="a">
</div>
```

I want to passing radio button data to select page from search page and save to new variable. example

```
 if (document.getElementById("onetrip").checked == true) {
            var is_round_trip = 0;
        }
        else if (document.getElementById("roundtrip").checked == true) {
            var is_round_trip = 1;
        }
```

this is my javascript on first page.

```
$(document).on('pagebeforeshow','#select', function(e,data){
            var is_round_trip = data.prevPage.find('#onetrip');
        });
```

But i always get undefined value of 'is_round_trip'.
Any solution if i want to get the value of is_round_trip based on radio button checked value from second page?

Comment: are you using _single page model_, each page in a separate file?

Comment: im using each page in separate file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED

I just add this to javascript. its return TRUE or FALSE

```
var is_round_trip = data.prevPage.find('#roundtrip').is(':checked');
```